# GAMS: Getting the n'th element of a vector

Tags: gams-math

I have a dataset in parameter variable

```
set t /t1 * t5/;
parameter mydata(t) /t1 10, t2 20, t3 30, t4 40, t5 50/;
```

How can I, the easiest way, get the ***n'th*** element of `mydata`. I am looking for something like:

```
display mydata(3)
```

where I will get the value `30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set t /t1 * t5/;
parameter mydata(t) /t1 10, t2 20, t3 30, t4 40, t5 50/;

scalar x;

x = sum(t$(ord(t)=3), mydata(t));

display x;
```